# Returning Anonymous Type

Tags: c#, .net, linq, return-type

I am using a trick to return Anonymous Type but, i m not sure whether it will
work in all scenario. If there is any problem using this trick plz let me know
so that i will not use this code in my project

```
class A
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class B
{
    public int AID { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}

private List<object> GetJoin()
{
    var query = from a in objA
                join b in objB
                on a.ID equals b.AID
                select new { a.ID, a.Name, b.Address };
    List<object> lst = new List<object>();
    foreach (var item in query)
    {
        object obj = new { ID = item.ID, Name = item.Name, Address = item.Address };
        lst.Add(obj);
    }
    return lst;
}
T Cast<T>(object obj, T type)
{
    return (T)obj;
}

//call Anonymous Type function
foreach (var o in GetJoin())
{
    var typed = Cast(o, new { ID = 0, Name = "", Address = "" });
    int i = 0;
}
```

Comment: The big question is: why don't you create a nominal type, and abandon these shenanigans entirely? `class NameAndAddress { public int ID { get; set; } public string Name { get; set; } public string Address { get; set; } }`. Problem solved.

Comment: Becoz for each & every linq query i dont want to create a class

Comment: You want to abandon type safety and readability to save you from writing a couple of properties? It sure doesn't take more effort than forcing you to create a dummy anonymous object for *each and every* time you want to *use* one. Cast-by-example is good for situations where the object type only matters to the caller. It is awful when it matters to the callee.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, that's guaranteed to work so long as everything is within the same assembly. If you cross the assembly boundary, it won't work though - anonymous types are internal, and the "identity" is based on:

- Assembly it's being used in
- Properties:

  - Name
  - Type
  - Order

*Everything* has to be just right for the types to be considered the same.

It's not *nice* though. For one thing, your GetJoin method can be simplified to:

```
return (from a in objA
        join b in objB
        on a.ID equals b.AID
        select (object) new { a.ID, a.Name, b.Address })
       .ToList();
```

... and for another, you've lost compile-time type safety and readability.

I think you'd be a lot better off creating a *real* type to encapsulate this data. Admittedly it would be lovely if we could create a named type which was the equivalent to the anonymous type, just with a name... but that's not available at the moment :(

Answer (score 0):

You cannot return Anonymous Types without using Object type. And using Object type, you lose member access.

You have two options:

- Create a type. (Recommended)
- Use *dynamic* type to access members

Comment: That's the whole point of the OP's `Cast` method. It uses cast-by-example to re-cast the `object` back to the correct anonymous type. Having said that, it's a *really* bad idea to do this in any non-throwaway code.